# Nested foreach loops in perl and variable scoping

Tags: perl, foreach, scoping

Ok this is a little weird and it doesn't seem to should work this way. I have a foreach nested in another and I need it to only grab the values that correspond to the outer loop.

```
foreach my $var (@$list)
{
    foreach my $var2 (@$list2)
    {
        if($var2->[0] ne $var->[0])
        {
            print qq(They are equal);
        } else
        {
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Is there a rule I should know about for scoping in nested loops? Testing is showing that once the inner loop is entered $var ceases to exist until the inner loop exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't seem to be working because you're testing if two strings are *not equal* and then printing that they are equal.

Also you should make that `print qq(They are equal\n);`

Incidentally, there is no issue with the scoping. Your strings are either matching or not matching--depending on which outcome you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks! you're right, incidentally I was also referencing a variable that wasn't getting set. It was a real newb moment. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @DeepThought: USUW -- `use strict; use warnings`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think scoping is your problem. You used **ne** and then printed "They are equal". If you're expecting them to be equal you should use **eq**. See below:

```
foreach my $var (@$list){
    foreach my $var2 (@$list2){
        if($var2->[0] eq $var->[0]) {
            print qq(They are equal);
        } else {
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is scope problem here since I face the problem in my code. when I print the variable in the outer foreach it printing correctly, but when I try to print the outer foreach variable inside the inner foreach it only print the initialized value of the outer variable.